# Monitors: going from VESA 100x100 to VESA 200x200 - adapter plates don't "adapt"?

Tags: display, adapter, vesa

This seems so incredibly simple, but after 6 months I still haven't found good solutions.  Everything thinks this *should* be possible, but turns out to be quite odd.

- Monitor arm with VESA 100x100 (and 75x75)
- Display with VESA 200x200 holes (but very lightweight)
- Would like to avoid drilling through metal or custom fabrication

Here's the things I assumed would work, but haven't:

Plan 1: Use a VESA adapter plate - they're all over the place!

The problem is these plates don't have the correct hole sizes for the VESA 200x200 side.  Although VESA 100x100 specs "M4" screws, the larger VESA 200x200 uses "M8" screws.  Invariably EVERY plate or set of brackets I tried didn't have a large enough hole for the M8 screws/bolts.  I brought an M8 bolt to Fry's and tried every single adapter that was on display, open or that I could open the box for, no luck.

This is maddening - what's the point of a standard if nobody follows it!?  The M8 bolt IS correct, I have it screwed into the display now - I didn't get that wrong - I have physical evidence that this is the correct size bolt.

You might ask "How can this seeming contradiction be true?"  I think larger mounting kits have large integrated brackets that DO have larger slots/holes.  So obviously if you use the full, wide, wall mounting bracket system from a vendor, you can mount the TV.  BUT these large integrated brackets can't be used as an adapter, it's an "all or nothing" package.

Plan 2: (originally plan 1) Use a two piece quick connect style mounting system

I really wanted this to work.  BUT most of these systems assume you're mounting a wall or stud or pole.  So, although they might accommodate the 200x200 end of things, they will let you secure the other end to VESA 75x75.

Eventual "Fix":

I eventually resorted to buying a set of 4 small brackets and modified them.  I bought a special drill bit for metal and reamed out the outer holes, to make them a bit bigger.

Although the result is nice, I wouldn't want to do that again.  Even using a vice, drilling these brackets was dangerous (for me), the drill pulled the brackets out of the vice, or jammed the drill, many times while doing these 4 holes.

Obviously somebody with proper metal shop skills could do this correctly / safely, but in the future I'd really like to use off-the-shelf parts.

Still Confused about M8 bolts and adapter plates, theories:

I still don't understand what the flat adapter plates are used for, how they would work for anybody.  It seems like everybody would have this problem on the 200x200 side?  Is it possible that some display vendors use smaller bolts at the 200x200 holes, and just ignore the spec?

Obviously they sell the adapter plates online, many types, so people are obviously able to make use of them?

Some of the holes on some plates seemed a bit larger, but NOT M8.  Maybe there's some intermediate size that's in common use, some pseudo standard?

Or maybe there's some type of "hole" adapter?  You put something into an M8 hole, and then it has a threaded hole to receive a smaller screw?  Can anybody explain this?

Or maybe the 200x200 side of the adapters are never screwed directly into the back of a TV?  Maybe they're always used with our parts from that vendor that also expects the smaller non-standard screws?

I'd love to hear comments from anybody that's used any of the adapter plates.  In particular, the outer patterns of holes, and the screws/bolts that went into them.

Since these questions all use common terms, I haven't been able to find any good info online, and I've looked and looked.